# how to make this pattern/effect

Tags: patterns

I was wondering whether there is a tutorial for making this effect; I'm referring to the dashes inside the dark purple container. Didn't know what to write in google to find something like that.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What have you tried? What has failed? What software are you using?

Comment: If you use Illustrator "Blending" makes at least resembling patterns easily. Blend differently rotated lines. Your lines seem to be more tightly packed in the right that in the left. Blending makes easily only uniformly distributed object clouds. Non-uniform distribution needs different tiling method. Inkscape has  more closely what you need in its Edit > Clone > Create Tiled Clones. Finally you can place manually rotated line segments to make an exact copy if that's needed.

Comment: You might search for "electric field grid" and similar searches

Answer (score 1):

My comment hasn't an image, but here's one to show what's easy in Illustrator:

[image]

1. A line and its 90 degrees rotated copy
2. Blendings. The blue column in the left is got by blending the lines in 1. with 6 intermediate steps. The blend is expanded to get a group of freely usable objects. The red column in the right is a group, too. It's made in the same way, but the top and bottom lines are equal. They are colored to red just for fun. Both groups are blended with 8 intermediate steps.
3. Blending settings are changed. This version has 10 intermediate steps.

**Warning:** Blending can easily make unexpected spaghetti if the blended objects have in some irregular way changing curve forms or directions or the number of the subobjects in groups differ.